# How to set array item with if statement

Tags: powershell

I am trying to loop though a pipe delineated file.
Each line of the file will look something like this

```
123456|Doe Jean|2019/04/16|NOTICE_xxx|pdfname_1.pdf
```

The NOTICE_xxx could be one of about 10 three digit numbers. I am currently looping though each line of the text file, splitting each line into an array `$linearray`, and would like to replace the `NOTICE_xxx` with some other text in that array. When I run the script I get this error

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
>   At C:\test\ArchiveNotice_Index_Maker.ps1:12 char:8
>   +     if($linearry.Contains('NOTICE_320')){$linearray[3] = "Notc - Notic ...
>   +        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

I have tried using an if elseif statement but it seems not to work.

```
#Set Fold Directory
$fileDirectory = "C:\test\"
#Loop though each line in file
foreach($line in Get-Content -Path $fileDirectory\index.txt){
$splitter = "|"
$linearray = $line.Split($splitter)

#Replace Notice Type With Notice Name
if($linearry.Contains('NOTICE_320')){$linearray[3] = "Notice Name 1"}
    elseif($linearry.Contains('NOTICE_322')){$linearray[3] = "Notice Name 2"}
    elseif($linearry.Contains('NOTICE_333')){$linearray[3] = "Notice Name 3"}
    elseif($linearry.Contains('NOTICE_351')){$linearray[3] = "Notice Name 4"}
    elseif($linearry.Contains('NOTICE_370')){$linearray[3] = "Notice Name 5"}
    elseif($linearry.Contains('NOTICE_372')){$linearray[3] = "Notice Name 6"}

  $noticeType = $linearray[3]

    write-host("$noticeType") 
}
```

Comment: i suspect it would be a great deal easier if you simply used `Import-CSV` with the `-Delimiter` set to `'|'. then you can use standard property tests and edits ... and gracefully export the data to a pipe-delimited CSV file. [*grin*]

Comment: You misspelled `$linearray` in all of your `.Contains()` calls.

Comment: I changed everything to the Import-CSV method that @Lee_Dailey suggested and it works great. Thank you

Comment: @zitheran - you are very welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Lee Dailey, this would be simplified by treating the file as a pipe delimited CSV file (which it sounds like it is). I would also suggest using the `Switch` statement rather than a whole lot of `If/ElseIf` statements. Assuming you do not have headers, you could do something like this:

```
#Set Fold Directory
$fileDirectory = "C:\test\"

#Import data
$Data = Import-Csv -Path $fileDirectory\index.txt -Delimiter '|' -Header 'ID','Name','Date','Notice','File'

#Loop though each line in file, and update Notice field
Switch  ($Data){
    {$_.Notice -eq 'NOTICE_320'}{$_.Notice = "Notice Name 1"}
    {$_.Notice -eq 'NOTICE_322'}{$_.Notice = "Notice Name 2"}
    {$_.Notice -eq 'NOTICE_333'}{$_.Notice = "Notice Name 3"}
    {$_.Notice -eq 'NOTICE_351'}{$_.Notice = "Notice Name 4"}
    {$_.Notice -eq 'NOTICE_370'}{$_.Notice = "Notice Name 5"}
    {$_.Notice -eq 'NOTICE_372'}{$_.Notice = "Notice Name 6"}
}
```

If you do have headers you can just leave off the `-header` part, and update `.Notice` to match your header name.

Alternatively you could use a hashtable to set the value like this:

```
#Set Fold Directory
$fileDirectory = "C:\test\"

#Import data
$Data = Import-Csv -Path $fileDirectory\index.txt -Delimiter '|' -Header 'ID','Name','Date','Notice','File'
#Map Notice codes to new names
$NoticeHT = @{
    'NOTICE_320' = "Notice Name 1"
    'NOTICE_322' = "Notice Name 2"
    'NOTICE_333' = "Notice Name 3"
    'NOTICE_351' = "Notice Name 4"
    'NOTICE_370' = "Notice Name 5"
    'NOTICE_372' = "Notice Name 6"
}
#Loop though each line in file, and update Notice field
$Data | Where{$_.Notice -in $NoticeHT.Keys} | ForEach-Object {$_.Notice = $NoticeHT[$_.Notice]}
```

Again, headers and what not, just like the first example.